# How can I clear the screen with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I clear or refresh the page in the browser using javascript? I have a loop that prints a string to the page each second and I want to clear the screen each time it updates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you append your string to the document body, you can just use

```
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to write it like this

```
 document.write(‘ ‘)
```